# Fiddler capture can't be re-enabled

Tags: fiddler

I'm having trouble using Fiddler - it was working fine yesterday and I didn't knowingly change any options. I've un-installed and re-installed Version 4.4.4.8 on Windows 7 box.

When I try to start capturing a yellow banner appears near the top of the Fiddler window claiming: "The system proxy was changed. Click to reenable Fiddler capture". I click on the banner and it redisplays the same message.

I'm sure I've done something dumb but I have no idea what it is. Thanks!

[Problem 'fixed'. Rebooted machine. Still don't understand original problem but I can now proceed. Logging off/on had not solved problem. Arg.]

Comment: If your proxy settings are being reset by another application, you can use Process Monitor from SysInternals to see who's writing to the ProxyServer key in the registry. Common culprits are AV products and networking clients (VPN software, ISA Firewall, TMG, etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue. I dont know the exact science of the cause but I know that Dropbox, putty, and filezilla, under certain situation, will unset proxy settings. The way I get fiddler to work again, is

1) shut down all browsers, fiddler, and all of the aforementioned programs, (or any other program that you might think might change proxy settings).

2)go to the start menu type in 'internet options'.

3)click Connections Tab; LAN settings button; Then make sure 'Use a proxy server for your LAN' is checked. (NOTHING ELSE).

4)Click the advanced button. In the 'Servers' section you need HTTP:127.0.0.1 port:8888 and Secure:127.0.0.1 port:8888. (This assumes that fiddler is using default settings).

5)Close the dialog windows. You should reopen the internet options to check that your changes saved. If they did not then something is preventing the change. Either way, try fiddler and see if its capturing again.

Things to remember. If you ever open a browser and cannot load any pages due to a proxy error, then you need to close all browsers and go to the internet options and set your LAN settings to 'Automatically detect settings'. When you close fiddler, this should be done automatically.